# Winforms Databinding and multiple Forms

Tags: winforms, validation, data-binding, focus

i have a main window that contains multiple UserControls, arranged as tab pages and tab groups (much like Visual Studio allows to have two or more editors visible at the same time).

I also have the possibility to open such an UserControl into a seperate floating window.

One of these UserControls contains simple form fields (e.g. text boxes). These text boxes are bounded with common databinding to an object / property. The binding mode is OnValidation (not on OnPropertyChanged).

When I switch the focus from this User Control inside the main window into another UserControl in the Main windows, the validation is automatically performed and the databinding is finised / the changed text will be set on the model object / property that is bounded to that text field.

But if I switch the focus to an UserControl which resides in another (floating) window, the databinding is not finished since no validation is performed.

I know that I can handle this manually by triggering ValidateChildren etc, but this seems to my the wrong way / is ugly.

Is there a "correct" / clean way to solve this issue? I want that the validation is performed as soon as the UserControl loses its focus or the window gets deactivated.

One information: On of my UserControls contains a TreeControl. If I edit a tree node label, and when I switch the focus to another (foating) window, the label edit is finished automatically. I want the corresponding behaviour for usual form fields regarding binding...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this. From the point of view of the control, it still has the focus (if you click the title bar or Alt-tab back to the main window, you will notice that the focus remains in the same control).  Its just that the form the control is on is not active.  If you want it to save changes when your form is deactivated, you must manually trigger it.  The best way to do that is probably to override the OnDeactivate method of the form.

```
    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivate(e);

        this.ValidateChildren();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For me, the question is still: Is this the way how tree control, grid controls etc. recognize the form focus switch, so do they provide an handler for the parent form Deactivated event, and do they track changes of the UserControl on ParentChanged event. Because, likein my use case, the same UserControl object can be moved between different forms. And for me, the whole required logic to solve such a simple problem seems to be to complicated...